# How can I change the edge line color when using the 'fill' function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, graphics, colors, plot, shapes

I'm writing code in which I use MATLAB's `fill` command to plot 2D shapes. I can specify the fill color of the shape. However, the border line color is always black. I want the border line color the same as the fill color. How can I also specify the border line color?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [this thread](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/5396):

```
To set the edgecolor to white do the following.

h = fill([-1 -1 1 1],[-1 1 1 -1],'w');
axis([-2 2 -2 2]);
set(h,'edgecolor','white');
```

that should take care of the border.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to [schnaader's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795618/matlab-how-do-i-the-line-color-when-using-the-fill-to-draw-2d-shapes/3795637#3795637), you can also set the edge color in the initial call to [FILL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fill.html):

```
hPatch = fill(xData,yData,'r','EdgeColor','r');  %# Red patch with red edges
```

Or stop the edges from being drawn altogether:

```
hPatch = fill(xData,yData,'r','EdgeColor','none');  %# Red patch with no edges
```